# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx

When I open my site, I get a 502 bad gateway error. After looking at the error log file in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, it mentions that "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream".

`nginx.conf` file content:

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  10240;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    client_header_timeout 600;
    client_body_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 6000;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    keepalive_timeout  36500;
    proxy_read_timeout 1250000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1250000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1250000;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";


  server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

How to solve this?

Comment: it's often due to unresponsive element you set in your config file, like static server could you ad a bit more details

Comment: Could you add your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to your question?

Comment: Please add any files you've edited in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but due to the rise of audience in our site, at first i did all suggestions i can find here "[How to fix gateway timeout?](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-error-using-nginx/)" and other sites and here in SO, and still had the same issue of 502 gateway error. So i caught the issue that the server i was working has a website and an apiend both in the same server, so i transferred the apiend onto another server which worked very well, until we got a lot more requests as our clients having more and more events and 502 gateway timeout issue came back, the apiend is still responding while the website is on 502.

So i tried checking all my server logs, until i checked my php-fpm.log and saw this errors:

```
[26-Mar-2015 10:10:04] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (35), consider raising it
[26-Mar-2015 12:04:52] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers)
```

As it said in my php-fpm.log i need to increase the max_children setting, on my `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` my current setting is:

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
```

Using this command: `ps -ylC php5-fpm --sort:rss` i checked for the average memory usage in kilobytes per process of php-fpm then compute for the pm.max_children.

**Calculating pm.max_children**

An example: if our cloud server has 4 GB RAM and a MySQL database service is running as well that consumes at least 1 GB our best aim is to get 4 - 1 - 0,5 (marge) GB = 2,5 GB RAM or 2560 Mb.

pm.max_children brings us to 2560 Mb / 60 Mb = 42 max_children

After i did this, it's been 8 months i haven't encountered the 502 gateway error and in also we checked our codes and found out that other developers code which were critical process were consuming a lot of resources so we still we made improvement on the backend codes as well.

Even if this posts is old, i just wanted to share how i resolved the issue. :D

Here is my reference.
[Determining the correct number of child processes for PHP-FPM on NGinx](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/determining-the-correct-number-of-child-processes-for-php-fpm-on-nginx)